# Replacing value with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two variables:

```js
var v1 = 'http://localhost/wa/pradeep'
var v2 = 'http://localhost/wa/pradeep/some/text'

var re = /(\/wa\/\w*\/?)/

var replaceValue = '$&/~tag/test'

console.log(v1.replace(re, replaceValue))

console.log(v2.replace(re, replaceValue))
```

I want to avoid two consecutive slashes from the second output. Can anyone guide me how can I achieve the same?

may be there is a way to conditionally check if second group is present and then add slash? I could not find a way to achieve it.

Edit: For the second case, there should a slash at the end (after 'test') For ex: 
http://localhost/wa/pradeep/~tag/test/some/text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep last `/` outside group and use back-reference of group #1:

```js
var v1 = 'http://localhost/wa/pradeep'
var v2 = 'http://localhost/wa/pradeep/some/text'

var re = /(\/wa\/\w*)(\/?)/

var replaceValue = '$1/~tag/test$2'

console.log(v1.replace(re, replaceValue))

console.log(v2.replace(re, replaceValue))
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you Anubhava :)

Comment: Anubhava, I need some little variation for the above question. I missed one important thing. for the ´replaceValue´, I want slash at the end for the second case and not for the first case. Could you please help with that? I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you. I will check in a moment. Basically I had the same idea of getting that in a second group which I did mention in my question. But didn't Know how to achieve it. Thank you again :)